# Magmi undefined offset

Tags: import, magmi

I don't know if I'm allowed to ask it here. But I will give it a try.

I've just setup Magmi (MAGento Mass Importer).

I first logged in with the default credentials : magmi:magmi

now i set up an admin account on my magento shop and connected via that one.

Now it gives me the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /magmi_auth.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /magmi_auth.php on line 45
```

I already googled this issue and I got the following answer:

*Specifically this happens if the session is still logged in with the default magmi:magmi and you successfully connect to Magento.

A quick work around is to clear the browsing history, then log in with the Magento credentials.*

I already tried that but this aint working.

someone help me please.